# ggplot2: Add a stacked bar showing the total distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following snippet creates stacked bars showing the distribution of "clarity" by "cut".

```
data(diamonds)
qplot(cut, data=diamonds, geom="bar", fill=clarity, position="fill")
```

Another plot shows the total distribution of "clarity" for the entire dataset.

```
qplot(x=factor(""), data=diamonds, geom="bar", fill=clarity, position="fill")
```

Is there a way to add the second plot as an extra bar to the first plot, say with label "total"?

[image: bycut]
[image: total]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many approaches but here's one:

```
diamonds2 <- diamonds
diamonds2$cut <- "Total"
diamonds3 <- rbind(diamonds, diamonds2)

qplot(cut, data=diamonds3, geom="bar", fill=clarity, position="fill")
```

[image]